# PDF Download error with Selenium, Pyinstaller (Python) in DRM environment

Tags: python, pdf, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller, drm

I tried designing a program to scrape information from a website and automatically download attached PDF files.

The program runs without any issues when execute it in VS Code, but it occured error when I run executable file (made exe with pyinstaller).

The Error is that the downloaded documents are corrupted and cannot be opened.

I try this program in my company, so every documents are must applied DRM automatically.

If there are any possible ways to improve this situation, you would like to know.

This is part of my Code about get browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import chromedriver_autoinstaller #type: ignore
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import openpyxl, pandas, requests, threading, datetime, xlwings # 외부 라이브러리
import os, time, shutil, getpass # 기본 라이브러리
from concurrent import futures
import sys, os

current_dir = "D:\\Python"
directory = current_dir.replace("\\","/",10) + "/"
chrome_down_path = current_dir+"\\Downloads"
down_path = directory+"Downloads/"

PartNumber = "JANTXV1N4616UR-1"
url = 'https://www.doeeet.com/home'

chrome_ver = chromedriver_autoinstaller.get_chrome_version().split(".")[0] #type:ignore
driver_path = f'./{chrome_ver}/chromedriver.exe'
if os.path.exists(driver_path):
    print(f"chrom driver is insatlled: {driver_path}") 
else:
    print(f"install the chrome driver(ver: {chrome_ver})")
    chromedriver_autoinstaller.install(True)

chrome_options = Options()
profile = {
            #"plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled": False, "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"}], # Disable Chrome's PDF Viewer
            "download.default_directory": chrome_down_path, #r"C:\Users\yunji.lim\Desktop\Data\Downloads",
            "download.prompt_for_download": False, #To auto download the file
            "download.directory_upgrade":True,
            "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True,
            "download.extensions_to_open": "applications/pdf"
            }
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",profile)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach",True)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options=chrome_options)
browser.maximize_window()
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
browser.get(url)

try : 
    WebDriverWait(browser,5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ngrv_"]/a'))
    )
finally : 
    element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ngrv_"]/a')
    element.send_keys("\n")
    element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="_58_login"]')
    element.clear()
    element.send_keys(user_id)
    element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="_58_password"]')
    element.send_keys(user_pw)
    element.send_keys("\n")

try : # 검색 가능한 상태까지 Wait (wait time : max 15sec)
    WebDriverWait(browser,15).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME,'q'))
)
except :
    pass
finally : # 검색 가능한 상태에 도달 하면 Part Number 검색 수행
    element = browser.find_element(By.NAME,'q')
    element.send_keys(PartNumber)
    element.send_keys("\n")
    
    try : # Part Number 검색 결과가 로드 될 때 까지 대기 (wait time : max 15sec)
        WebDriverWait(browser,25).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, PartNumber))
        )
    except :
        pass
    finally : # 클릭 가능한 상태에 도달하면 검색 결과 클릭
        search_res = browser.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT, PartNumber)
```

I tried to --hidden-import options when i made exe file using pyinstaller.
But it did not works.

Also, I tryied this.

Case 1. I ran Chrome with the executable I created using pyinstaller, and automatically downloaded the pdf. In this case, there is an error in the downloaded pdf file, so I can't open the file.

Case 2. I ran Chrome with the executable I created using pyinstaller, and downloaded the pdf myself. In the same case, there was an error in the pdf file, so I couldn't open it

Case 3. Turned on Chrome myself, accessed the website and downloaded the pdf. In this case, the pdf file opens well. Therefore, there is no problem with the original pdf file on the website.

Comment: what is the error message and where is the rest of the code ?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The error message did not occur. I want to upload executable code, but the website needs login. Please understand that I can't upload the entire code.
When I run Chrome from the exe file, I saw an error, so I only uploaded that part because I thought the code written above might be the cause.

Comment: I runed this code outside the company and I checked that the pdf download and pdf viewing are working normally. 
I think there's a conflict with the company's security program. 
I had also errors with Excel due to DRM, 
so I modified the code to use xlwings instead of openpyxl. 
I wonder if there's a way like this for pdf as well.